# Jenkins Pipeline Post Action sshPublisher not working when status is ABORTED

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

In a Jenkinsfile, the post block `always` using `sshPublisher` seems to be bugged to me. It is not executed if the build status is `ABORTED`.

Let's suppose I have the following `Jenkinsfile`:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        // setup
    }
    stages {
        stage("Build") {
            // build
        }
        stage("Deploying for review") {
            steps {
                sshPublisher(publishers: [sshPublisherDesc(configName: "foo", transfers: [
                    sshTransfer(execCommand: "docker run --rm -d -p $PORT:443 " +
                        " --name '$PROJECT-$DOCKER_TAG' bar.foo.com/$PROJECT:$DOCKER_TAG")
                ])])
            }
        }
        stage("Review") {
            agent none
            steps {
                input "Deploy to production?"
            }
        }
        stage("Promotion") {
            steps {
                echo "Promotion"
            }
        }
        stage("Deploying to production") {
            steps {
                echo "Deploy to production"
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        always {
            sshPublisher(publishers: [sshPublisherDesc(configName: "foo", transfers: [
                sshTransfer(execCommand: "docker stop '$PROJECT-$DOCKER_TAG')
            ])])
        }
    }
}
```

If the user aborts the build in the `Review` stage, the following output will be generated and the `docker stop` command in the `post` block is NOT executed.

```
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Review)
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] input
Deploy to production?
Proceed or Abort
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Promotion)
Stage "Promotion" skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Deploying to production)
Stage "Deploying to production" skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Post Actions)
[Pipeline] step
SSH: Current build result is [ABORTED], not going to run.
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
```

Firstly, why is `sshPublisher` not executed if the build result is `ABORTED`? And if there is a valid reason, how can I enforce it to run still?

Comment: Btw, I do realize that the primary purpose of `sshPublisher` is not to remotely execute `docker stop`... If there are better approaches, please let me know.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Jenkins pipeline Declarative Post Action section is not executed if the job is ABORTED by the user. Kindly let me know if you have found solution for same.